# How to use the gather environment to center align a different number of equations on each line?

Tags: equations, align, gather

I want to have 3 equations on one line, and 2 equations on the next line. I want them in the style of gather, i.e. they should be centre aligned in each line. This is what I want it to look like:
[image: what i want]

What is the right way to do this? (I have used two separate align environments to get this image. Clearly, the line spacing between them is too much)

Comment: please provide a small document that makes the image, to save people having to type the all in to test answers. That said I would just centre the first three as a block, so use `gather` but put `\qquad` between each of the equations on the same line

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \delta B_1,  \delta B_1 \neq \phi 
\qquad
A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq, A_3\subseteq A_4
\qquad
B_1\subseteq B_2\subseteq, B_3\subseteq B_4\\
\implies
A_1 \cap A_2, A_3,A_4,A_5=\phi
\qquad
B_1 \cap AB_2, B_3,B_4,B_5=\phi
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

or `gather*` if no numbers required.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\delta B_1,  \delta B_1 \neq \phi  &&
A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq, A_3\subseteq A_4  && B_1\subseteq B_2\subseteq, B_3\subseteq B_4
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\implies A_1 \cap A_2, A_3,A_4,A_5=\phi &&  B_1 \cap AB_2, B_3,B_4,B_5=\phi
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656553/equation-alignement-with-different-numbers-of-columns-spacing-issues) and the answer given by user187802, maybe this will make you happy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\delta B_1,  \delta B_1 \neq \phi  &&
A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq, A_3\subseteq A_4  && B_1\subseteq B_2\subseteq, B_3\subseteq B_4
\end{align*}%
\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}%
\begin{align*}
\implies A_1 \cap A_2, A_3,A_4,A_5=\phi &&  B_1 \cap B_2, B_3,B_4,B_5=\phi
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Blop]

I find the answer of David Carlisle good but unsatisfactory since `\quad` is a constant spacing distance and so does not give an automatic placement of the equations. Furthermore, I added to the answer of user187802 the command `\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}` to have a normal spacing between the two equations.

I hope this helps.