# Equation alignement with different numbers of columns - spacing issues

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

Good day everyone.

I have a set of 4 equations, that have respectively 2, 1, 3 and 3 columns, and that I want to "align" with each other in a particular way. I want all to be centered with respect to the page and the two lasts (with 3 columns) to be aligned with each other. Here are two unsuccessful attempts I made.

First trial:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        [P_\mu, P_\nu] &= 0, &
        [M_{\mu\nu}, P_\lambda] &= \eta_{\nu\lambda} P_\mu - \eta_{\mu\lambda} P_\nu,
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        [M_{\mu\nu}, M_{\lambda\sigma}] 
        &= \eta_{\mu\sigma} M_{\nu\lambda} + \eta_{\nu\lambda} M_{\mu\sigma} - \eta_{\mu\lambda} M_{\nu\sigma} - \eta_{\nu\sigma} M_{\mu\lambda},
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
        \Delta(P_\mu) &= P_\mu \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes P_\mu, &
        \varepsilon(P_\mu) &= 0, &
        S(P_\mu) &= - P_\mu, \\
        \Delta(M_{\mu\nu}) &= M_{\mu\nu} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes M_{\mu\nu}, &
        \varepsilon(M_{\mu\nu}) &= 0, &
        S(M_{\mu\nu}) &= - M_{\mu\nu},
    \end{align}
    \label{eq:poincare_hopf_alg}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

This one is perfect but there are extra vertical spacing between the `align` environment... Note that I don't want to use this solution with `\vspace{-20pt}`, or equivalent, because vertical spacing of equations is automatically generated by LaTeX: in other words I would have to change the value of the spacing each time I change my code.

Second trial:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
    \begin{aligned}
        [P_\mu, P_\nu] &= 0, &
        [M_{\mu\nu}, P_\lambda] &= \eta_{\nu\lambda} P_\mu - \eta_{\mu\lambda} P_\nu,
    \end{aligned} \\
    \begin{aligned}
        [M_{\mu\nu}, M_{\lambda\sigma}] 
        &= \eta_{\mu\sigma} M_{\nu\lambda} + \eta_{\nu\lambda} M_{\mu\sigma} - \eta_{\mu\lambda} M_{\nu\sigma} - \eta_{\nu\sigma} M_{\mu\lambda},
    \end{aligned} \\
    \begin{aligned}
        \Delta(P_\mu) &= P_\mu \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes P_\mu, &
        \varepsilon(P_\mu) &= 0, &
        S(P_\mu) &= - P_\mu,
    \end{aligned} \\
    \begin{aligned}
        \Delta(M_{\mu\nu}) &= M_{\mu\nu} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes M_{\mu\nu}, &
        \varepsilon(M_{\mu\nu}) &= 0, &
        S(M_{\mu\nu}) &= - M_{\mu\nu},
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Here, the vertical spacing is correct but the horizontal one is not. I want my equation to be equally separated on the width of the page, just like `align` does (see trial 1).

Thanks in advance for your time!

**EDIT 1:**
My question seemed not so clear so let me precise. When I use `align` alone with multiple columns, LaTeX makes sure to divide the page width equally for each column (it kind of "justify" the equation). But now I have a block of equations with different numbers of column. I want some to be aligned (like the third and fourth) and the other to be centered/"justified".

I proposed a possible solution based on Celdor proposed command line `\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}`. Other more automatic way of doing this are welcome.

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        [P_\mu, P_\nu] &= 0, &
        [M_{\mu\nu}, P_\lambda] &= \eta_{\nu\lambda} P_\mu - \eta_{\mu\lambda} P_\nu,
    \end{align}%
    \vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}%
    \begin{align}
        [M_{\mu\nu}, M_{\lambda\sigma}] 
        &= \eta_{\mu\sigma} M_{\nu\lambda} + \eta_{\nu\lambda} M_{\mu\sigma} - \eta_{\mu\lambda} M_{\nu\sigma} - \eta_{\nu\sigma} M_{\mu\lambda},
    \end{align}%
    \vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}%
    \begin{align}
        \Delta(P_\mu) &= P_\mu \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes P_\mu, &
        \varepsilon(P_\mu) &= 0, &
        S(P_\mu) &= - P_\mu, \\
        \Delta(M_{\mu\nu}) &= M_{\mu\nu} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes M_{\mu\nu}, &
        \varepsilon(M_{\mu\nu}) &= 0, &
        S(M_{\mu\nu}) &= - M_{\mu\nu},
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

**EDIT 2:**
I realized my question was related to the unsatisfactorilly answered [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488217/how-to-use-the-gather-environment-to-center-align-a-different-number-of-equation?rq=1).

Third trial:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    &a = 0,
    &
    \mathllap{[M_{\mu\nu}, P_\lambda] = \eta_{\nu\lambda} P_\mu - \eta_{\mu\lambda} P_\nu,}
    \\
    &b = 0,
\end{alignat}%
\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}%
\begin{align}
    \Delta(P_\mu) &= P_\mu \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes P_\mu,           &      \varepsilon(P_\mu) &= 0, &      S(P_\mu) &= - P_\mu, \\
    \Delta(M_{\mu\nu}) &= M_{\mu\nu} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes M_{\mu\nu}, & \varepsilon(M_{\mu\nu}) &= 0, & S(M_{\mu\nu}) &= - M_{\mu\nu},
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

[image: My trials]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Example 1.

[image]

Code to the Example 1.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}
\kant*[1][1-2]
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    &[P_\mu, P_\nu] = 0,
    &
    \mathllap{[M_{\mu\nu}, P_\lambda] = \eta_{\nu\lambda} P_\mu - \eta_{\mu\lambda} P_\nu,}
    \\
    &[M_{\mu\nu}, M_{\lambda\sigma}] = \eta_{\mu\sigma} M_{\nu\lambda} + \eta_{\nu\lambda} M_{\mu\sigma} - \eta_{\mu\lambda} M_{\nu\sigma} - \eta_{\nu\sigma} M_{\mu\lambda},
\end{alignat}%
\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}%
\begin{align}
              \Delta(P_\mu) &= P_\mu \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes P_\mu,           &      \varepsilon(P_\mu) &= 0, &      S(P_\mu) &= - P_\mu, \\
         \Delta(M_{\mu\nu}) &= M_{\mu\nu} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes M_{\mu\nu}, & \varepsilon(M_{\mu\nu}) &= 0, & S(M_{\mu\nu}) &= - M_{\mu\nu},
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\kant[1][1]
\end{document}
```

---

Update.
Below are added two examples which demonstrate a usage of `flalign` ("full length alignment") to horizontally justify and distribute equations over the page.

`\ineqskip` is a macro with `\vspace{...}` to work out space between separate environments and maintain continuation between equations. The components are

- `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`--glues added before and after each equation environment
- `\baselineskip` is a space between two subsequent lines, and
- \jot` is space between subsequent lines within an equation environment.

Additionally, `\abovedisplayskip` and  `\belowdisplayskip` seem to be affected by `\baselinestretch` and are therefore multiplied by the latter factor.

---

Example 2.

[image]

Example 3

[image]

Code to the Example 2

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
  \renewcommand{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{red}}

\newcommand\ineqskip{
  \dimen0=\dimexpr+\abovedisplayskip+\belowdisplayskip\relax
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\dimen0-\baselineskip+\jot}}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    [P_\mu, P_\nu] &= 0, &
    [M_{\mu\nu}, P_\lambda] &= \eta_{\nu\lambda} P_\mu - \eta_{\mu\lambda} P_\nu,
  \end{align}%
  \vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}%
  \begin{align}
  [M_{\mu\nu}, M_{\lambda\sigma}]
    &= \eta_{\mu\sigma} M_{\nu\lambda} + \eta_{\nu\lambda} M_{\mu\sigma} - \eta_{\mu\lambda} M_{\nu\sigma} - \eta_{\nu\sigma} M_{\mu\lambda},
  \end{align}%
  \vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip+\jot}%
  \begin{flalign}
    \Delta(P_\mu) &= P_\mu \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes P_\mu, &
    \varepsilon(P_\mu) &= 0, &
    S(P_\mu) &= - P_\mu, \\
    \Delta(M_{\mu\nu}) &= M_{\mu\nu} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes M_{\mu\nu}, &
    \varepsilon(M_{\mu\nu}) &= 0, &
    S(M_{\mu\nu}) &= - M_{\mu\nu},
  \end{flalign}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Code to the Example 3

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% ... preamble is the same as in the Example 2

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{flalign}
    [P_\mu, P_\nu] &= 0, &
    [M_{\mu\nu}, P_\lambda] &= \eta_{\nu\lambda} P_\mu - \eta_{\mu\lambda} P_\nu,
  \end{flalign}%
  % ... the rest of the middle part is the same as in Example 2
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Celdor, and thank you very much for your answer ! The display in my particular case works fine indeed, but let me be picky. You aligned all equations so that it looks like what I want, but I want that "solitary" equations (first and second) are aligned only with respect to the page width and the two other equations (third and fourth) to be aligned with respect to the other. Let me know if I am not clear.

By the way, can you detail what are `\mathllap` and the arguments of your `\vspace` ?

Comment: "_I want that "solitary" equations (first and second) are aligned only with respect to the page width_" and this means you want them centred, separately? So actually the second attempt is correct regarding first two equations?

Comment: I cannot figure out why the other two equations (3rd and 4th) are wrong. If I refer to your answer, the first attempt is perfect apart from the extra spacing. I can see equations form three columns in two rows and each column is aligned by `=`. How do you want them to be aligned with each other if centring is wrong and aligning by `=` is also wrong?

Comment: `\mathrlap{}` is a class of macros that instructs LaTeX to create a box of zero length while  the content is still typeset. Then, its argument is pushed towards left. It is useful if you don't want the content to create unnecessary space in aligned equations ([here is an article](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~aperlis/publications/mathclap/)). The `\vspace{}` simply takes negative space created by two consecutive equations.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers ! I edited my question to precise what I meant. Also you can check my third example to see why I was picky.

Comment: Furthermore, please can you detail the **arguments** of your `\vspace` ?

Comment: @OursPolaire I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\IEEEeqnarray` from `IEEEtrantools`. See a manual at https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}


\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:poincare_hopf_alg}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl ' rCl ' rCl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{9}{c}{
  [P_\mu, P_\nu] = 0,
  \hspace{4em}
  [M_{\mu\nu}, P_\lambda] = \eta_{\nu\lambda} P_\mu - \eta_{\mu\lambda} P_\nu,
} \\
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{9}{c}{
  [M_{\mu\nu}, M_{\lambda\sigma}] 
  = \eta_{\mu\sigma} M_{\nu\lambda} + \eta_{\nu\lambda} M_{\mu\sigma}
  - \eta_{\mu\lambda} M_{\nu\sigma} - \eta_{\nu\sigma} M_{\mu\lambda},
} \\
\Delta(P_\mu) &=& P_\mu \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes P_\mu, &
\varepsilon(P_\mu) &=& 0, &
S(P_\mu) &=& - P_\mu, \\
\Delta(M_{\mu\nu}) &=& M_{\mu\nu} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes M_{\mu\nu}, &
\varepsilon(M_{\mu\nu}) &=& 0, &
S(M_{\mu\nu}) &=& - M_{\mu\nu},
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]